# Video sharing site with embeddable upload control

Tags: video, vimeo, video-embedding

I'm in the process of building a site with embedded videos. I'd prefer not dealing with the videos myself and instead use something like Vimeo Plus. I also would like the future administrators of the site to be able to upload videos directly from the administration interface of the site (i.e. so that they don't have to go to Vimeo for uploading). Vimeo doesn't appear to have an embeddable upload control. I could upload the videos to my server first, and then transfer it to Vimeo using their API, but a lot of things can go wrong in the process...

Has anyone found a video service with an embeddable upload control, or solved this problem some other way?

UPDATE: Looks like [bitsontherun](http://www.bitsontherun.com/api-documentation/) may be an option, or perhaps [brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/products/developer-tools/technology-integrations/). (Neither turn out to have prepackaged upload component).

Answer (score 1):

Brightcove is definitely one way to go.  They have full API's that allows you build a component for upload. They also provide a batch ingest process.  I know this doesn't solve your embeddable component desire, but this can get on your way to creating one.

Answer (score -1):

I just deployed a site where the administrators can upload videos to the server using [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)'s upload functionality hooked into a Drupal site.  Security isn't as much of a worry since the capability is locked down by role, and like you say you can do whatever you want with the video file once it's on your server.